# Problem filtering GET query by id in asp.net core. Getting the correct amount of rows but all are exactly the same

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the following Query in Postman https://localhost:44300/api/ViewEvents?Id=Bob. Instead off returning 4 different rows containing the ID Bob, it returns 4 of the exact same rows. Any help would be appreciated.

API Controller

```
// GET: api/ViewEvents
       [HttpGet]
       public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ViewEvents>>> GetViewEvents(string id)
       {

           if(id == null)
           {
               return await _context.ViewEvents.ToListAsync();
           }
           else
           {
               
               var viewEvents = _context.ViewEvents.Where(i => i.Id==(id)).ToList();
               if (viewEvents.Count < 1)
               {
                   return NotFound();
               }
               
               return viewEvents;
           }
       }
```

Database view returns correct results.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `tim_azure`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view_events` AS
    SELECT 
        `e`.`CreatedUserID` AS `id`,
        `e`.`ID` AS `eventid`,
        `e`.`Event` AS `event`
    FROM
        `tblevent` `e`
```

The below image contains database restults.
[DataBase Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HLhH.png)

Comment: Please add your database data in your question .

Comment: Note that Views in MySQL have limited access to underlying indexes, rendering them (in my 'view') almost entirely useless.

Comment: @Strawberry I've tried querying the table directly with the same method and it yields the same results. So you think the problem stems from MySQL?

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi I've added an Image of the database results. Thanks for your input.

Comment: No; I suspect the problem relates to how you're processing the result set, but of course I may be mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I changed my query to the below and it worked for some reason.

```
       var viewEvents = _context.Tblevent.Where(i => i.CreatedUserId == (id));
        if (id == null)
        {
            return await _context.Tblevent.ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
           

            if (viewEvents.ToList().Count < 1)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return viewEvents.ToList();
        }
    }
```